# How to deploy XML file with my web application?

Tags: asp.net, xml, deployment

I've written an ASP.net web application.  In the interest of following the advice in "The Pragmatic Programmer" to put application logic in configuration, I wrote a large XML file that describes various business rules.

When I test the application on my local development workstation, I copy the file to `c:\xxxxx\myfile.xml` and then write the code to read the file from this location.

What is the correct way to deploy this xml file as part of my web application so that it gets read from the directory in which the web application is deployed?

**Update:** The XML file in question is for server-side configuration and should **never** be available for download to the end-user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're not embedding this as a resource, you should:

1. Create a directory under which this file will reside.
2. Create the file and set its Build Action to Content.
3. Create a web.config file in that directory which forbids access to the directory so you don't expose your business rules to the Internet.
4. Add a setting in your application's main web.config that gives the path to this file relative to the root of the application, i.e. "~/MySecureFolder/MyBusinessRules.Xml".
5. Have some code that calls [HttpServerUtility.MapPath Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) to convert the value from the setting in web.config to a virtual path.

Comment: +1: Thank you! This works, but I was hoping that a more elegant solution may exist.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you want - Click on the XML file, then open the Property Window and find the "Build Action" property. Set the value to "Embedded Resources"

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is:

1. Add the XML file to your web application project in Visual Studio
2. Right click on the file and select 'Properties...'
3. Set the **Build Action** to 'Content' and **Copy to Output Directory** to 'Do not copy'

this will ensure that your XML file is deployed along with the rest of your web app.

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon - because otherwise the file will be copied to your output directory - which in the case of a web app is the bin folder. Setting the Build Action to 'Content' ensures that the file will be treated in the same way as an ASPX/ASHX/ASCX in your site, so there's no need for an extra copy in the bin.

Comment: Following your directions, when I deploy the application to the target directory, I don't have the file there at all, so how do I make my application read the file at run-time?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to make available your XML file from http requests to your server, you should 
place it in your web publication folder.

This ASP instruction should help you to find your publication path:
Request.ServerVariables("APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH")

Comment: No, I want to use the XML file for server-side configuration.  It should never be downloaded by the client.